# Android/iOS keyboard: stickers API

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, emoji

I was searching for a way to create a custom keyboard to add custom emoji and stickers. 
So far I've figured out that emoji are just unicode characters and in order to add custom emoji one should supply a custom font with the dedicated emoji mapped to a predefined unicode character inside the font. This font should be available across users of the app in order for the custom emoji to display correctly.

The question arises when it comes to stickers (those big images available to add for example in Facebook comments). I can't find any useful information on how they work and what is the interface to embed them in the custom keyboard and to paste further to a text. There are apps available on Google Play and AppStore that does it (like "Go Keyboard" app for example)
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**So the question is:**

How to embed stickers into a text to share further to 3rd-party apps? My main idea is to understand if there is a common standard or API for stickers (like for emoji)? Or the only way to use stickers is to use/build a custom chat API with a backend server which means only apps that use the same service will reliably decode the shared text to display stickers correctly?

Comment: Download quickblox demos. They are using stickers you might get idea from that

Comment: @Harry Thanks a lot for the reference, it definitely makes sense. However from what I can see QuickBlox is a chat service with it's own backend and mobile SDKs. There is no doubt it's possible to build custom API to embed any feature into a message including stickers. However what I'm looking for is a kind of common standard  for embedding stickers into a message so it's possible to share the message to other apps that support stickers (just like emoji does). Is it possible or I misunderstood the way stickers work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working in an iOS project to prove this concept of using emojis and stickers in chat conversations.

You can check it out in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cairano/CIStickerFacilities) and contribute if you want (review and improvement are welcome).

What I done was, use the `NSTextAttachment` to attach an image within an `UITextView`, using the `NSAttributedString` object type.

**To show a image as an emoji, within in an UITextView:**

```c
// initialize object with the content of textView
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textview.attributedText];

// initialize selected image to be used as emoji
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MicheyMouse"];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:25 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[attributeString appendAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];

// blank space after the image
NSAttributedString *blank = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
[attributeString appendAttributedString:blank];

textview.attributedText = attributeString;
```

**And if you wanna use the image as a sticker, follow this lines:**

```c
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:sticker];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:12 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]; // --> change de scale, to change image size (or create the image in size that you want)

NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = attrStringWithImage
```

In this example, I attached the image as a sticker directly in a cell (you can do this cell as a chat ballon).

In other words, in the first code lines, I basically showed the image in an UITextView, and in the second I put the image directly in chat lines.

I had to do my own sticker/emoji keyboard and I also made some work to handle the switching between emoji keyboard and typing keyboard.

This is the GitHub repository for the project example: https://github.com/cairano/CIStickerFacilities